# Running Rails application in docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, docker, debian

I want to run a Rails 4.2.1 application in a docker container on a debian machine.

When I run bundle exec rails s I got this error:

```
Could not find json-1.7.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I run bundle install I got this error:

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150604-137-10l84fa.                                                                                              rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:0:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function 'fbuffer_to_s':
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: macro "rb_str_new" requires 2 arguments,    but                                                                                                only 1 given
 VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                           ^
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:20: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer                                                                                             without a cast
 VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                ^
 Makefile:237: recipe for target 'generator.o' failed
  make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

  make failed, exit code 2

 Gem files will remain installed in /var/www/test/xyz/vendor/bundle/ruby/2                                                                                              .2.0/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/www/test/xyz/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x                                                                                                86_64-linux/2.2.0/json-1.7.7/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Whats going wrong? what can I do now?

Comment: Can you try doing `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` first

Comment: Can you show a reproducer, your Dockerfile and some more data ?

Comment: @AnantKolvankar I got this error: 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1 directory.

Don't have a dockerfile I'm using the default debian docker container.

Comment: I think there  is a issue with your docker container

Comment: and what kind of issue?

Comment: I deleted the container and created a new one ... now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[docker-rails](https://github.com/alienfast/docker-rails) is a project I just created to make rails with docker (and CI) *very easy*.  I think it can help you and reduce the amount of configuration necessary to get up and running with rails on docker.

It creates a global shared gem volume (to speed up bundler), and has a sample Dockerfile for use.

Given that native error, I'm guessing your Dockerfile is missing a needed package, you may need to update your `apt-get` statements.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. This error is because of the versions of ruby softwares (gems) that we uses doesn't match at some point.

You are using ruby version 2.2.1. Your Gemfile contains the gems of older versions and it depends on json version 1.7.7.

You should install the following ruby version:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p448
```

to get rid of the error, OR updating your gems that compatible with ruby version 2.2.1 will do the trick.